# 100% cpu usage profile output, what could cause this based on our profile log?

Tags: node.js, profiling, cpu-usage, v8

We have a massively scaled nodejs project (~1m+ users) that is suddenly taking a massive beating on our CPU. (Epyc 24c 2ghz)

We've been trying to debug what's using all our CPU using a profiler, (and I can show you the output down below) and it's behaving really weirdly whatever it is.

We have a master process that spawns 48 clusters, after they're all loaded the cpu usage slowly grows to max. After killing a cluster, the LA doesn't dip at all. However after killing the master process, it all goes back to normal.

The master process obviously isn't maxing all threads, and killing a cluster should REALLY do the trick?

[image: profile]

We even stopped the user input of the application and a cluster entirely and it didn't reduce cpu usage at all.

We've got plenty of log files we could send if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the profile, it looks like the code is spending a lot of time getting the current time from the system. Do you maybe have `Date.now()` (or oldschool, extra-inefficient `+new Date()`) calls around a bunch of frequently used, relatively quick operations? Try removing those, you should see a speedup (or drop in CPU utilization, respectively).

As for stopping user input not reducing CPU load: are you maybe scheduling callbacks? Or promises, or other async requests? It's not difficult to write a program that only needs to be kicked off and then keeps the CPU busy forever on its own.

Beyond these rough guesses, there isn't enough information here to dig deeper. Is there anything other than time-related stuff on the profile, further down? In particular, any of your own code? What does the bottom-up profile say?

Comment: The initial profile was taken with node-tick-processor, but when we re-analysed the profile with node's builtin --prof-process feature things mostly pointed to epoll_pwait hogging ticks. Here's a full report of that: https://aeth.dev/AWb

We did have some event listener callbacks and setIntervals, but we unregistered these callbacks and cleared the intervals. We're fairly certain the process was almost entirely idle (we still had our connection for runtime execution).

Comment: AFAIK `epoll_pwait` means the process is waiting for something (e.g. filesystem or network). From the bottom-up profile, you can see that function `wsEvent` from `/home/melmsie/dank-memer/node_modules/eris-sharder/node_modules/eris/lib/gateway/Shard.js:211:12` is quite busy -- maybe that helps narrowing down what's going on?